# Interconnection of SIP applications

Tags: networking, sip, skype

As far as I know, there are many applications using SIP : ekiga, linphone, even skype, … Are those device all able to work with each other? I mean, if I register with, say, linphone, will someone on skype be able to ring me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skype is not using **SIP**. But if you interconnect any **SIP** system then there are plugin available like SipTheeSkype, SIP to Skype Gateway, Skype with asterisk & some other.

By using that plugin you can interact with Skype network from your **SIP** network.

As far as concern to other **SIP** **client** they are all interact with each other if they don't have any proprietary header check to register with specific server only.